# Android Raw Folder Media Player

Tags: android

I have two activity Play.java and Home.java,Home.java contain onclick function for Listview and get the position of listview
I Need to Pass that position to Play.java.when i click listview "unfortunately app closed"

Home.java

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     
    int songindex = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    p1.listen(songindex);
}
```

Play.java

```
public void change(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void listen(int songindex)
    {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
     if(songindex==0)
     {
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
        mp.start();



     }
     else if(songindex==1)
     {
         mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brahma);
         mPlayer2.start(); 
     }
    }
```

when i click song from listview its not working app closed

Comment: stacktrace from logcat?????

Comment: please see logcat and see what problem ...and put that logcat screen short.

Comment: write th pay code in onCreate method of  Play.class

Comment: fist i need to know whether coding right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass position using intent.

```
Home.java

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     
    int songindex = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Play.class);
    intnt.putExtra("position",position);
    startActivity(intent);

  //  p1.listen(songindex);
}
Play.java

public void change(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void listen(int songindex)
    {
     Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
         int position = data.getInt("position");

    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
     if(songindex==0)
     {
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
        mp.start();



     }
     else if(songindex==1)
     {
         mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brahma);
         mPlayer2.start(); 
     }
    }
```

Comment: @PrabuJM: What exactly you want to do

Comment: when i click songs name on listview song should play from raw folder and when i ckick next next songs previous song shoud stopped

Comment: Yo want to change intent or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Put listen function in main file

```
Home.java

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{     
    listen(position);
}


    public void listen(int songindex)
    {



    MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
     if(songindex==0)
     {
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gayatri);
        mp.start();



     }
     else if(songindex==1)
     {
         mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brahma);
         mPlayer2.start(); 
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

LogCat should bring light to you problem, but we still don't have it.

Then why do you need mp and mp2? To play two songs at once?

I would just have one mp, declared in the class, not in the method, because in you case the refrence to mp2 player is lost after exiting from the listen method, and there is no way to control it (in fact, it may even stop playing after exiting from the method).

To make in short, this is what I suggest:

```
MediaPlayer mp; 

static final int table[] songIndexIds= { R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2};


public void listen(int songIndex)
     if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
     }

     if (songIndex >= 0) {
         mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, songIndexIds[songIndex]);
         mp.start();
     }

}

// "Destructor"
@Override 
public void finalize() {
     if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
     }

}
```

Comment: Replace R.raw.song1 and R.raw.song2 by real resource id-s